# How to define a class that has a relationship with other classes

Tags: python, class, oop

I tried to define the class `Interaction` that had a relationship with other classes (`Teacher` and `Student`) as follows

```
class Teacher(Person):
    def __init__(self, age: int, subjects: list[Subject] | None = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(age)
        if subjects is not None:
            self.history = subjects
        else:
            self.history = []
        self.current = []
        
    def start_new_subject(self) -> None:
        self.history.extend(self.current)
        
        
class Interaction:
    def __init__(self, teacher: Teacher, students: list[tuple[str, int]]) -> None:
        self.teacher = Teacher
        self.students = [name(year) for name, year in students]
        self.teacher.start_new_subject()
```

If I instantiated the class `Teacher` and called on its `start_new_class` function, it worked as expected

```
>>> mr_A = Teacher()
>>> mr_A.start_new_subject()
```

However, when I instantiated the class `Interaction`, I got an error:

```
>>> Interaction(teacher=mr_A, students=[(Math, 10)])
TypeError: Teacher.start_new_subject() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I'm at a loss what it meant by `missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

What did I do wrong? Could someone please show me how to define the class `Interaction` correctly?

Comment: `start_new_subject` isn't in your code. Can you update the code in your question so the error matches.

Comment: `self.teacher = Teacher` is just a reference to a class, you're not creating an instance of `Teacher` class and won't have access to instance attributes. I think what you need to have there is `self.teacher = teacher` since the `__init__` of `Interaction` takes a `teacher` argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT*: Someone's already answered this in a comment on OP it seems.

Assuming you meant to write `start_new_class` instead of `start_new_subject`, the issue you're seeing arises because of the following line:

```
self.teacher = Teacher
```

This is setting the `teacher` member equal to the `Teacher` class, not the instance of the `Teacher` class. Thus, when you call `self.teacher.start_new_class()`, what you're effectively writing is `Teacher.start_new_class()`, which won't work according to how you've defined the `Teacher` class.

Instead, you should write `self.teacher = teacher`, because `teacher` is the function parameter variable. Then, you'll be operating on an instance of `Teacher`.

Comment: Thank you. Was the class `Interaction` called a *composition* class?

Comment: @Nemo it is using composition, yes. Practically any class you will write will use composition.